# What does each column on a rinex GNSS observable file mean?

Tags: gps, epoch, galileo

I am trying to understand the data from a GNSS observation rinex file but cannot figure out what each column represents as the PDF (for rinex 3.02) is not very clear.

I would like to know what each column in the epoch corresponds to. Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: Did your search give you anything? Please always search before posting a question here. You will likely find a better answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

The columns are the observations (pseudo ranges/code, carrier phase, dopper, snr/cn0). The problem/issue with RINEX that you have is the order of columns is arbitrary. The columns are specified in the RINEX header.

If you post an example I will expand on my answer. Post the header, and an example line/row.